# what grep -oh "[*?<com]" do?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I am trying to achieve something and in the experiment I came through following case , could somebody explain me how to understand whats happening.

```
echo " Agent process not running on www.raja.server.local.com" | grep -oh "[*?<com]"
o
c
o
o
o
c
c
o
m
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the grep manpage:

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
```

In this case, the `-h` is a no-op.

`grep` is looking for each of the characters: `*`, `?`, `<`, `c`, `o`, and `m` in the input string that you piped to it, and printing each one on a new line as it finds it.

```
$ echo Zcom\?\<\[\*Z
Zcom?<[*Z
$ echo Zcom\?\<\[\*Z | grep -oh "[*?<com]"
c
o
m
?
<
*
$
```

Also, if you use `grep --color -h "[*?<com]"` you'll see the same letters in the same order highlighted inside the echoed search string.